# Is there a JIra query which will return all stories without an EPIC?

Tags: jira, jql, epic

I'm trying to tidy up our Jira board and create an accurate story map.

To do that I need to come up with a query that will return open user stories within a certain project that don't have any issue links (preferably 'related to (primary)')- the last part does not seem to be supported.

I've had a look around an post of the Q&As are a few years old, so i'm wondering if it was been updated recently?

*I'm using version 5.1*

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a throwaway JIRA Agile board for the project and look at the No Epics area in the Epic column on the left. If you want to do it in JQL alone you can use:

Comment: "Epic Link" is empty. Gosh, I don't like the way that stackoverflow decides when to submit text.

Answer (score 12):

issuetype = Story and "Epic Link" != EMPTY

Comment: this doesn't answer the question correctly. rather, this would return all stories WITH an epic.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following query:

project = PROJECTNAME AND issuetype = Story AND "Epic Link" is EMPTY

Seems to work for me, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `"Epic Link" = EMPTY`, you might want to filter out issues that, themselves, are EPICs, since they can't have Epic Links and will otherwise show up in the search.

Here's a search to get *only* issues that have no Epic (but are not Epics themselves):

```
issuetype != Epic AND "Epic Link" is EMPTY
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another answer into the bowl.

You can use your normal workboard (Scrum, Kanban, etc) and **add a swimlane** with the JQL:

```
"Epic Link" is EMPTY
```

Just did this for our board after looking exactly for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points for comments or votes yet ... but to add to the one answer provided about the "Board", the JQL will work in a simple issue search as well.   I just ran this JQL from Issue Search and it worked like a champ:

```
project = BI and "Epic Link" is empty
```

Comment: This will return Epic tickets as well, since Epics can't have Epic Links. Perhaps it works for you if you don't have any Epics in that project?

Answer (score -1):

project = *PROJECT* NAME AND issuetype = *ISSUETYPE* AND "Epic Link" = EMPTY